# How to replace wingpanel's "Applications" text with a icon in Freya

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, themes

I was previously wondering how I go about replacing the text at the top left of the [wingpanel](/questions/tagged/wingpanel) from 'Applications' to the official Elementary OS logo. I found a solution to this question posted on Reddit which I have posted below. I hope this helps anyone who hasn't previously found this answer.

Comment: this is not working or i am not able to change this! eOS Loki

Comment: I haven't tested this out with Loki only for Freya

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [elementaryosnewbie's answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3fzd6s/tutorial_how_to_replace_the_applications_text_on). Thought it'd
be best to have this on the Elementary OS Stack Exchange. Big thanks
to him for sharing it. If this has already been posted I apologies for
the double post.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

- Open file manager up as administrator and go to: `/usr/share/themes/name-of-your-theme-folder/gtk-3.0`
- Place the icon you want to use in that folder.
- Make sure the icon has proper permissions by right clicking on it, choosing `properties` > `more` > and making it `644-777` (read, write, and
  executable by owner, group, everyone) or else wingpanel may not load.
  (Alternatively you could issue `chmod 777 <icon name>.svg`)
- Open up `/usr/share/themes/name-of-your-theme-folder/gtk-3.0/apps.css` in
  Scratch, scroll down to the panel settings, find `.panel-app-button`,
  and change what's in the {brackets} to what's below. (Default theme:
  `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0` )

```
.panel-app-button > GtkWidget > GtkWidget:first-child {
    padding: 0px 24px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    background-image: url("icon.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

- Change the background image URL to the name of the icon that you placed in the `gtk-3.0` folder. The padding above is adjusted for a
  24x24 icon but you can adjust it to fit something
  bigger/smaller/wider, just change "24px" to the width of your image.
- In terminal type: `killall wingpanel` to see the changes.

  **Some icons you may like**
- [image] - [bulls-eye
  icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Go3.png)
- [image] - [apple
  icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kd3x.png) (Image may not be visible here
  because its color matches the background here.)

**Search google for more**

https://www.google.com/search?q=menu&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:24,iszh:24,ic:trans&tbm=isch&cad=h

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more in Loki.

Comment: will it work on Loki?

Comment: When you are referencing someone's material, please use blockquote and Do mention the author's name first including the source link. Please read, [How to reference material written by others](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Thank you!

Comment: Excuse me @Hasan? I had already mentioned the author's name and included a link to their original post.

Comment: @Hasan you cannot just wrap the entire answer in a blockquote. The first paragraph are his own words. I think you did this to mimic the example in your link, but keep in mind that that example answer (that contains the quote) itself is treated as a quote on that page, hence it *is* wrapped in another quote there.

Comment: @Hasan You have wrapped entire answer in a blockquote which is not allowed. Change it.

Comment: I apologize for the situation and accept things went wrong by my edit. I have accidentally rejected Wolverine's edit which I can't approve anymore. I ask someone to edit the post again and I will be able to approve it then. I am sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

Place the logo file on `/usr/share/themes/yourtheme` location.

Now open the `app.css` file, remove the existing code and add this code:

```
/*********
 * Panel *
 ********/

.panel {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    background-image: url("elem.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel .menubar:first-child {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

Now, kill the panel:

```
killall wingpanel
```

the rest of things will handled by cerbere.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

For ElementaryOS Loki users to replace the "Applications" text in the wingpanel with an icon:

open **/usr/share/themes/yourtheme/gtk.css** or
**/home/username/.themes/yourtheme/gtk.css**

copy desired icon (*icon.svg* in this example) to this folder and add:

```
.panel {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("icon.svg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel .menubar:first-child {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

If you selected "prefer dark variant" in elementary-tweaks, you may need to change gtk-dark.css instead of gtk.css

Answer (score 1):

I also added:

```
background-position: 6px 0;
```

so the icon would line up with the icons in the dock (assuming you have the dock on the left). You might have to tweak it depending on the size of the icon you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to add icon instead the name applications.

[image]

Edit `/usr/share/themes/yourtheme/gtk.css` and add:

```
 /*********
 * Panel *
 ********/

.panel {
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url("elementaryicon.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size:0px !important;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

I search now to remove the name applications.