# how to change text "applications" to icon elementaryos loki

Tags: release-loki, elementary-website

anyone know how to change text "applications" menu to icon?

I have google and try follow instruction in here

[How to replace wingpanel's "Applications" text with a icon in Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/how-to-replace-the-applications-text-on-the-wingpanel-with-a-icon)

but stuck in step 4
maybe that tutor for freya, bcoz I cant find .panel-app-button

thanks

Comment: Questions with outdated answers should have a comment posted there.