# Replacing "Applications" in the panel button with an icon

Tags: wingpanel, applications

In freya it was possible to do this by editing apps.css in your theme of choice per [How to replace wingpanel's "Applications" text with a icon in Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/how-to-replace-wingpanels-applications-text-with-a-icon-in-freya) . So far as I can tell there's no such setting there any more.

This may seem a tiny annoyance but since I swap between osx and eos every day it just plain stabs me in the eyes to have some generic "Applications" text there rather than a lovely elementary logo. Is this setting accessible in a file somewhere or do I have to learn enough to hack on wingpanel to make such a thing happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7843/5565, which was redirected to the Freya page. I think the idea is that someone will respond with an answer there.