# Editing (customization) wingpanel elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Tags: wingpanel

The latest updates missing some settings from app.css for wingpanel as well as from dconf. In what direction to go to change the panel since the screenshots?

[image]
[image]

sorry for my English

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to visit [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/how-to-replace-wingpanels-applications-text-with-a-icon-in-freya) link for the first part of your question.

The easiest possible way of changing the date and time format is to type these two commands in your terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "custom"
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M"
```

where:

%A - The full weekday name according to the current locale.

%d - The day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31).

%B - The full month name according to the current locale.

%Y - The year as a decimal number including the century.

%I - The hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number (range 1 to 12); single digits are preceded by a blank. (See also %I.) (TZ)

%M - The minute as a decimal number (range 00 to 59).

In your case, to display time only, you will probable need only %I and %M

Be sure to check [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) link for more detailed explanation of date and time symbols.

**Update:
Icon instead of text is not available for Loki anymore**

Comment: You answer for elementar icon instead of Applications is for Freya - in Loki it doesn't work anymore (as commented in your link)

Comment: Please make sure you read the whole answer and then write a comment. At the end there is an explanation

Comment: Yeah, I see. But it doesn't solve my problem with panel button :<

Comment: That is because there is no solution for this particular problem, for current Loki version. If I find any solution I will post here.