# How to replace "Applications" with the eOS logo?

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, applications, icons

I would like to replace the top left wingpanel "Applications" text with an .svg icon.

I saw a post from 2016 but it's not revelant for eOS 5.0 Juno ([How to replace wingpanel's "Applications" text with a icon in Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/how-to-replace-wingpanels-applications-text-with-a-icon-in-freya))

There is no such thing as `.panel-app-button`

Anybody have an idea ?