# How to replace wingpanel's “Applications” text with a icon in Elementary OS 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, themes

I was wondering how I go about replacing the text at the top left of the 
`wingpanel`  from **Applications** to the official Elementary OS logo. Can anyone please help me there is a similar question posted on this site but doesn't work for the current version of OS.
The link to the similar questoin is '''[How to replace wingpanel's "Applications" text with a icon in Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/how-to-replace-wingpanels-applications-text-with-a-icon-in-freya)'''

Comment: The only way is to find where it is in wingpanel. There is wingpanel official repo at git. So download, change and then compile. You can search my posts about wingpanel here. I described how to modify wingpanel and compile it. The problem is that every time wingpanel will be updated by the system updater or via the terminal by apt upgrade, it will overwrite the change and you will have to change it every time. The only way to make it easier is to rearrange wingpanel and write additional code which will be responsible for easy changing the text to logo. If you need a guide I can create it.

Comment: Sir, it would be very nice of you if you create the code. The reason i am not doing it myself is because I am still learning to use it properly and also i tried some other modifications to my theme which broke the UI so i had to reinstall it.

Comment: Hello I am not developer of Elementary OS.

Comment: Okay I guess we will have to wait for someone to make a proper mod file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The final solution: How to replace the magnifier/search icon using Inkscape**

See like this as an example:

```
 /usr/share/icons/McMojave-circle-dark/actions/symbolic/system-search-symbolic.svg
```

So replace the icon using

```
sudo inkscape (to run as root)
```

with the elementary OS logo. I suppose you know how to open the mentioned svg file in Inkscape and do it. Save it. Then hide the Applications name using my method described above and the issue is solved.

Examples of paths where the icon can be stored:

```
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/64x64/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/96x96/actions/system-search-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/actions/system-search-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/McMojave-circle/actions/symbolic/system-search-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/McMojave-circle-dark/actions/symbolic/system-search-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/Paper/scalable/actions/system-search-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/24/system-search-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/symbolic/system-search-symbolic.svg
```

Or just replace the file. Zipped logos for you.

[Zipped logos in new format](https://we.tl/t-9aVAY0kqF8)

[Zipped logo in old format](https://we.tl/t-OWUMs9NDQW)

Explanation: [Types of Elementary OS logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Elementary_logo.svg)

OR //update Feb2021
go to usr/share/icons/Themename/actions/symbolic/ and rename the system-search-symbolic.svg file to something else ,say system-search-symbolic1.svg and save the icon you intend to use as system-search-symbolic.svg.
This is a low skill ,reversible workaround for the guys who are not to confident with command promt or editing .css files.

Comment: WOW!!!!! That worked thank you very much @Sysadmin

Comment: You welcome. :) Older logo looks much better IMHO. Anyway I did it on my machine and I think this way is much easier, than changing the source code and recompiling it - yes, this is also possible and I know how to do it, however I always bear in mind, that each time the Elementary OS developer releases the upgrade it overwrites the change. This way with css and icon replacement it will not overwrite it and even after the upgrade it will be still the way it has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution which removes Applications name from the panel**

If you do not have vim, then install it with below command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Then type in terminal for example like below: (bear in mind that Nordic is a name of my theme which I am using currently, the default one is /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk.css)

```
 sudo vim /usr/share/themes/Nordic/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

hit button with symbol / on a keyboard type .panel.maximized to find this section and hit enter.

hit insert to edit file

comment it out like that for example:

```
/** .panel.maximized {
    background-color: #000; }
 **/
```

and then put this into this file below the commented our fragment:

```
.panel.maximized > .horizontal:first-child > :first-child, 
.panel.color-dark > .horizontal:first-child > :first-child {
    font-size:0px;
}
```

hit esc on a keyboard and then type :x and hit enter to save and exit.

Log out and log in again. Applications text will disappear.

Source: [Remove the Applications text on the top panel in Elementary OS](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gj6l0n/thinner_titlebars_how_to_make_elementaryos_look/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Comment: I guess it works only with selected themes as I trued with elementary-x and Flat-Remix-GTK-Blue-Darkest-NoBorder but no result....

Comment: Can You provide a link where I can download elementary-x theme please? I will test it.

Comment: OK. Got it: https://github.com/surajmandalcell/elementary-x

Comment: Solution added above for elementary-x

Comment: u can modify `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file instead it doesn't require *sudo*

Answer (score 2):

**For elementary-x theme you need to edit it here:**

```
/home/yourusername/.themes/elementary-x/gtk-3.0/apps.css
```

or if you have it in:

```
/usr/share/themes/elementary-x/gtk-3.0/apps.css
```

Depends on where did you install the theme for user or for all users.

https://github.com/surajmandalcell/elementary-x/blob/master/README.md

As you can read here:

```
 git clone https://github.com/surajmandalcell/elementary-x.git ~/.themes/elementary-x
```

This copies the git to user location.

```
 sudo mv /home/yourusername/.themes/elementary-x /usr/share/themes
```

will move it to the location where the theme will be accessible for all users - just an explanation for those who have only one machine and many users.

Check this: https://github.com/surajmandalcell/elementary-x/blob/master/gtk-3.0/apps.css

So the tutorial will look like this below:

Type in terminal for example like below: (bear in mind that elementary-x is a name of my theme which I am using currently, the default one is /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk.css)

```
sudo vim /usr/share/themes/elementary-x/gtk-3.0/apps.css
```

hit button with symbol / on a keyboard type .panel.maximized to find this section and hit enter.

hit insert to edit file

comment it out like that for example:

```
/** .panel.maximized {
     background-color: #000; }
 **/
```

and then put this into this file below the commented our fragment:

```
.panel.maximized > .horizontal:first-child > :first-child, 
.panel.color-dark > .horizontal:first-child > :first-child {
    font-size:0px;
}
```

hit esc on a keyboard and then type :x and hit enter to save and exit.

Log out and log in again. Applications text will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is wrong, below is correct solution. Treat this as a way of investigation, please.**

Above

```
 /** .panel.maximized {
    background-color: #000; }
 **/
```

You will find:

```
/*********
 * Panel *
 ********/
.panel {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;}
```

Change it to:

```
/*********
 * Panel *
 ********/
.panel {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  background-image: url("elementaryicon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size:0px !important; }
```

And put the elementary os icon 15x15 px or 20x20 px in directory where gtk.css or apps.css file is located. See guide above.

The only one thing left to solve it - how to get rid the magnifier icon.

Small edit:

The text is hard-coded here: https://github.com/elementary/applications-menu/blob/master/src/Indicator.vala#L75, and the icon three lines below that: https://github.com/elementary/applications-menu/blob/master/src/Indicator.vala#L78

I also wish they were customizable, but I doubt upstream is interested in supporting this kind of minor tweak (The elementary OS design is intended to be good enough that small tweaks like this are not important).

Anyway I will try to download it and recompile it the way I want. Just need to figure it out, where or how this search icon is rendered. Then the simple replacement and recompilation should just replace the search icon with the Elementary OS logo.

Comment: >The text is hard-coded here, and the icon three lines below that

>I also wish they were customizable, but I doubt upstream is interested in supporting this kind of minor tweak (The elementary OS design is intended to be good enough that small tweaks like this are not important).

Copy pasta from [my reply to one of the times this question was asked on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gj6l0n/thinner_titlebars_how_to_make_elementaryos_look/fqle1uv/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)