# Removing or disabling the wingpanel in 5.1 Hera without breaking the system

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel

I'm somebody who personally likes switching up the UI of my devices every few months, so I recently decided to ditch plank and wingpanel in favor of xfce4-panel. Ditching plank turned out to remove elementary os tweaks as well, but at least I found a hacky method of hiding it so it didn't get in the way, so I didn't even need to uninstall it. Wingpanel proves to be more challenging, as it removes pantheon-xsession-settings and pantheon-shell along with it, therefore preventing me from being able to log in. Unlike Plank, Wingpanel doesn't even have customization in the slightest, so I see no way of removing it or disabling it, and there seems to be no results on Google about it. This is the point where I would switch to Debian but I don't want to go through the work of distro hopping and I don't want to give up Elementary OS's user friendliness. How can I remove wingpanel, or disable it, or at the very least make it completely invisible like I did with Plank?

Comment: What do you mean writing that wingpanel does not have customization?

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/17213/19988

Comment: How to customize wingpanel. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/24530/19988

Comment: One more customization. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/24223/19988

Comment: I found that first one. It seems to only work on 5.0. On 5.1 there's no default values there are all. @Sysadmin

Comment: There is a modified version which autohides when the app active window is maximized: https://github.com/quequotion/wingpanel You can compile it from the source. Install dependencies and install it according to the guide they provided.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it gone completely as it conflicts with the xfce4 panel. I ended up devising my own solution, though. I posted it as an answer. @Sysadmin

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up devising my own hacky solution to get rid of it. I made a bash file titled `/usr/bin/nowingpanel` and in it, I put this...

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    sleep 1
    killall wingpanel
done
```

I made it an executable and put it in the startup applications and now wingpanel is no more.

Comment: Yes, you can kill wingpanel with 1s delay after startup using the Bourne bash script. Nice workaround. Upvoted.